# Request failed with status code 401 even when I passed the api token

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, post, axios

I'm trying to do a POST request with VueJS in Laravel, but the request failed with 401 status code, I'm passing the token into the headers but it doesn't work.

```
const post_data = {
   headers: {
      Authorization: [api token]
   },
   params: {
      [parameters]
  }
}
axios
   .post('URL', post_data)
   .then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: How are you passing the token? `Authorization: "Bearer " + token`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Authorization: "Bearer " + token or Authorization: "bearer " + token
```

In some cases, only one of the above works!